# spark 2.0.0 select distinct unstable result

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm running pyspark2 over spark 2.0.0

Considering stable and constant dataset loaded into Dataframe, I do drop duplicates by certain column:

```
vw_ticket = read_csv(...)
vw_ticket_in_booking = vw_ticket.dropDuplicates(['BOOKING_TICKET_ID'])
vw_ticket_in_booking.createOrReplaceTempView('vw_ticket_in_booking')
```

And then

```
spark.sql('select count(distinct(booking_id)) from vw_ticket_in_booking t').show()
```

gives unrepeatable results, **different** numbers, but

```
spark.sql('select count(distinct(booking_id)) from vw_ticket t').show()
spark.sql('select count(*) from vw_ticket t').show()
spark.sql('select count(*) from vw_ticket_in_booking t').show()
```

are always stable. What can be the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dropDuplicate` is like doing `groupBy` then `first`. There's going to be a shuffle and write to sort values to group them before deduplicating them.
This will lead to different lines being in the first place.

If you have an idea of which line value you want to keep you should apply a window function to assess which row is the first one (a `sort` won't be enough since there will still be a shuffle afterwards).